# Apache FOP transformation.transform is taking huge time

Tags: java, pdf

We are using template based approach to generate PDF files and for that we are using velocity as the template engine and Apache FOP as the PDF engine.

We are having the requirement to generate PDFs which can contain 0.2M table rows.
Following is the code which we have written. MyBean is the java bean class which will have 0.2 rows

```
velocityContext.put("MyBean", myBean);
final ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\test\\output.fo");

template.merge(velocityContext, writer1);
writer1.flush();
writer1.close();
```

My velocity template is sth like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
     <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="mybean"
                               page-height="29.7cm"
                               page-width="37cm"
                               margin-top="1cm"
                               margin-bottom="2cm"
                               margin-left="1cm"
                               margin-right="1cm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

  #foreach($grid in $MyBean.grids)
    #set($Griddata=$grid)
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="dashboard" initial-page-number="$count">
       force-page-count="no-force" keep-with-previous.within-page="always"
                    keep-with-next.within-page="always">
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"
                        keep-with-previous.within-page="always"
                        keep-with-next.within-page="always">
                        <fo:block keep-with-next.within-page="always"
                            keep-with-previous.within-page="always">
                            #parse('GridBody.fo')

                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
```

Now in GridBody.fo i am creating table and rows and cells.

So there is not issue with velocity as i am getting the output properly from velocity.

My rest code is sth like this

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream outStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

        FopFactory fopFactory;

        FOUserAgent foUserAgent;

        fopFactory=PDFExportContextInitializer.getFopFactoryInstance();
        foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        foUserAgent.setConserveMemoryPolicy(true);

        final Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent,outStream1);

        final Source src = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray()));
        src.setSystemId("123");

        final Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        final Transformer transformer = transFact.newTransformer();
        System.out.println("created transformer ");
        transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");
        transformer.transform(src, res);


        StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
            public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
                try {
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
                    oos.writeObject(outStream1.toByteArray());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    throw new WebApplicationException(e);
                } finally {
                    if(outStream1!=null) outStream1.close();


                }
            }
        };
```

Now the main issue is with transformer.transform as it is taking nearly 70 seconds to process 20k records.
My JVM settings are

```
-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Xmn256m
```

So i am not sure how to achieve the milestone of 0.2M when it is taking more than 1 minute to download just 20k records.

BTW ours is a WEB APP and the user can download 0.2M records.

Even i took the dump of velcoity output in afile and found the size to be around 150MB. May be because of which transformer is taking so much amount of time.

Is there not a way that we can switch of pasring and validations and just go directly to FOP to generate the pdf.